# Emit the first successfull result from Mono.first

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have two `Mono`s that either return a `404` or yield a `result`.

How can I combine these two `Mono`s that

- the `result` is emitted as soon as one the `Mono`s completes successfully.
- an `Optional.empty` is returned as soon as all `Mono`s yield a `404` or face any other error?

I tried

```java
      Mono<Result> mono0 = client.get()
          .uri(uri1)
          .retrieve()
          .bodyToMono(Result.class)
          .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.never());

      Mono<Result> mono1 = client.get()
          .uri(uri2)
          .retrieve()
          .bodyToMono(Result.class)
          .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.never());

      return Mono.first(mono0, mono1)
          .blockOptional()
```

The problem with this approach is that it never completes if both `Mono`s yield an error...

I think I need something like `OnErrorDetach` ....!?

To make the problem clearer I created a TestCase:

```java
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

class DummyTest {

  public Optional<String> getResult(Mono<String> m1, Mono<String> m2) {
    return Mono.first(m1, m2)
        // DoSomethingHere ?!??!?
        .blockOptional();
  }

  @Test
  void testFirstSuccessfullAndSecondErrorMono() {
    Optional<String> result = getResult(Mono.just("Something"), Mono.error(new RuntimeException()));

    assertThat(result, is(Optional.of("Something")));
  }

  @Test
  void testSecondSuccessfullAndFirstErrorMono() {
    Optional<String> result = getResult(Mono.error(new RuntimeException()), Mono.just("Something"));

    assertThat(result, is(Optional.of("Something")));
  }

  @Test
  void testTwoErrorMonosYieldEmpty() {
    Optional<String> result =
        getResult(Mono.error(new RuntimeException()), Mono.error(new RuntimeException()));

    assertThat(result, is(Optional.empty()));
  }


}
```

Comment: if you read the documentation, `Mono#first` does not invoke any logic, it will only select which mono that completes first, no matter if it has an error or not.You wan't to implement some logic, i would recommend implementing `Mono#zip` that will wait for both monos to finish and then you can implement your logic and select what to happen.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to wait for the second Mono to finish if the first Mono is already successfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with `Mono.first()` is that it takes the first *signal* (not the first value), so you end up trying to delay the corresponding `Mono` forever to get it not to replay the completion signal. You instead want something to take the first *value*.

Instead of `.onErrorResume(e -> Mono.never());`, use `.onErrorResume(e -> Mono.empty());`. You can then use:

```
Flux.merge(mono0, mono1).next();
```

The `merge()` (as oppose to `concat()`) combined with `next()` should ensure the first value is taken and the other ignored. You can of course still `blockOptional()` if you wish.

Comment: Addendum - I *believe* you can also just use `mono0.or(mono1);` and it'll take the first value rather than the first signal, but I'm currently not sitting in front of anything I can use to verify that. I'll try to check later.

Comment: nope, `Mono.first(a, b)` is same as `a.or(b)` (one is the factory method, the other an instance method, but the implementing operator underneath is the same)

Comment: @SimonBaslé Thanks for the confirmation - I checked that last night and meant to delete that comment, but clearly didn't! I think the docs should be clearer - the docs say `Emit the first available *result* from this mono or the other mono` for `Mono.or()`, which seems confusing (Mono.first() references *signal* instead, which seems much clearer.)

Comment: indeed ! this question revived the idea that a `firstValued` variant could be useful, and clarifying the javadoc could go along introducing that variant

Comment: @SimonBaslé Yes, that makes sense (I'd agree that a `firstValue()` variant would be a useful method - dare I say it, I think I can see more use cases for that than the current `first()` (first signal) method.)